# React Native Configuration Problems with gradle tool

Tags: windows-10, java, android

When I run `gradlew clean` inside my react native project I get the following error:

> Value 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid).

I am just able to run `gadlew clean` inside my android directory in my react native project and I'm using windows 10.

Below are my configurations:

- `JAVA_HOME:C:\Users\rvmelo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`
- `Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin`
- `Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin`

I already tried to change my `gradle.properties` file which is inside the android directory with the following:

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211

After I do this it still does not work and my java is running normally because when I type `java -version` I can see the version of java I'm using. The version is: `1.8.0_211`

Does anyone one knows how to fix this?!